# No mounting a USB pendrive on Debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, mount, usb-storage, dmesg

The system seems to know that my pendrive in insert, but when I try to mount it, I cannot do it 'cause it not appears in /dev/.

I post the result of command

> dmesg | tail -n 6

```
[  647.763175] usb 2-1.2: new high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[  647.856809] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=0302
[  647.856820] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  647.856827] usb 2-1.2: Product: STORE N GO                    
[  647.856832] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Verbatim                      
[  647.856837] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 000000000000447C
```

as you can see, no device is bound with my pendrive and I don't know how to mount it.
I really don't know what I have to do!

Any ideas???

Comment: try this line in terminal `sudo ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/*usb*` and see if anything shows up

Comment: Cannot access to /dev/.... : File or directory does not exist.

Comment: It's strange because few days ago I mounted the pendrive on /dev/sdb1

Comment: If you really don't have a /dev directory something is really hosed and you need to reinstall.

Comment: I resolved!!! The module of usb_storage was not loaded!

> sudo modprobe usb_storage

but I don't understand why the module is not loaded automatically on start-up! why??

Comment: Note (to myself, at least): i had a similar problem but the cable was the culprit. The device was charging but nothing happened on my computer (no new line in dmesg) when pluging with this bad usb cable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal output should also include something like:

```
[26789.560701] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[26789.560878] scsi6 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[26789.561162] usb-storage: device found at 3
[26789.561164] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[26789.561171] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[26789.561174] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[26794.561205] usb-storage: device scan complete
[26794.561792] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Ut165    USB2FlashStorage 0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[26794.562205] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[26794.562912] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 3948544 512-byte logical blocks: (2.02 GB/1.88 GiB)
[26794.563404] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[26794.563407] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[26794.563409] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[26794.566665] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[26794.566669]  sdc: sdc1
[26794.690926] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[26794.690930] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[26795.736708] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[26795.759838] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

This happens if the `usb_storage` is not loaded, you can check it out with:

```
lsmod | grep -i usb_storage
```

if it shows no output then it means that the module is not loaded; load it with:

```
sudo modprobe usb_storage
```

If everything then works you can make things persistent with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo usb_storage >> /etc/modules'
```

But I don't know why such things happen.

Comment: Thanks man! It seems that you have big experience with this kind of issues... :P